# See if I can "lose the funhouse."

Tags: meaning

A: Is there a passenger?
B: Well, this (camera's)angle’s not helping us. Maybe this(another camera) will. See if I can lose the funhouse.

I looked up 'funhouse' in a dictionary.
It says 'funhouse' is a ghost house.
I also looked up 'lose the funhouse' in a dictionary, and there is nothing.
Is there a special meaning for 'lose the funhouse'?

I can't understand what it means.
They(A & B)'re looking for a criminal who run away through CCTV footage.

Help me. T_T

Comment: can you provide the source of the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without more context I can't say for sure, but this is likely a reference to "funhouse" mirrors, which distort an image, as below, for humorous effect:

[image]

The lens or the angle of the first camera was likely causing distortion, but Speaker B felt the other camera would correct that distortion (i.e., "lose the funhouse" aspect).

<sub>Image borrowed from the [Fabius Maximus website](https://fabiusmaximus.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/funhouse-mirrors-2.jpg).</sub>

Comment: You can get a smartphone app which adds a "funhouse" effect to its camera image. Strangely my first search hit was a Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506617/android-camera-preview-with-funhouse-mirror-effect) with the same image.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That image was on the first page of Google searches and represented the concept best, so I'm not surprised someone else picked it as well. Low-hanging fruit!.